# How to emulate a virtual USB drive in Windows?

Tags: windows, usb, emulation, virtual-disk, bus

I have a remote server where I should test work of some application with USB drive. Unfortunately, there is no ability to install any USB drive there. So, I need to emulate a virtual USB drive in Windows. Application checks the disks that are on USB bus type:

```
 Get-Disk | Where-Object { ($_.BusType -eq "usb")
```

Is there any way to emulate a virtual USB drive in Windows?

Comment: Try to look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20599782/virtual-usb-device-for-windows. it may be what you are looking for

Comment: if I understand it correct it just shares USB functionality over  network. It is not a solution in my case because I'm using VPN connection (pretty slow) to my remote server

Comment: FabulaTech solution, is a tool which can map a USB storage over network. But a paid software. They offer trial with limited features. Take a look and check whether the solution is applies to your need

Comment: Maybe some ramdisk solutions can create virtual drives in RAM, but over a 'USB' layer of the OS, like you want. A good start point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RAM_drive_software

Answer (score 1):

If the solution may cost anything, you can use a lan attached usb hub (like [digi anywhere](https://www.digi.com/products/usb-and-serial-connectivity/usb-over-ip-hubs/anywhereusb) from [www.digi.com](https://www.digi.com)). You can attach any usb devices over the lan (even smartcards and dongles) to the server. The shipped driver behaves like a real usb port.

We made good experiences with the digi solution, but there more cheaper ones offered which promise the same functionality. Check before if the driver is suited for your server OS.